# There is a way to deactivate all breakpoints in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, breakpoints

I was wondering if there was a way to disable all breakpoints in visual studio 2019, like chrome ...

I saw that there is the possibility to disable bookmarks but I did not find anything regarding breakpoints.

Every time I have to remove dozens of breakpoints and then put them back and it's quite annoying...

I hope I haven't duplicated a question.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: VS IDE - > Debug -> Remove / Disable all breakpoints option is there. You can temporarily disable or completely remove. Temporary disable is preferred, similarly you can enable all or pick and choose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the breakpoint window, there is a series of buttons to enable/disable/remove breakpoints (and other operations)

you can open the breakpoint window from the Debug menu

look it up.